# is it normal to have Mappers and Extractors for each domain model?

Tags: spring, class, dao, jdbctemplate

I am working on my Payroll program, currently I have 6 packages, and in total I have 22 classes, is that okay? I have 4 domain models, and each of them have mappers and extractors. and I have other classes as well, is this good???

EDIT
Here have  a look
Employee,User,Person,Contact
My[image: Package Explorer]

Comment: can you provide more details on how you organized your classes, did you leverage a layered approach, how many dao's are there? 6 packages and 22 classes does not tell much.

Comment: Here I provided a screenshot, please have a look :)

Comment: Are these classes to extract elements from JDBC result sets and assign them to properties on your objects? If this is the case you might want to consider an ORM such as Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Rowmappers and ResultSetExtractors are similar (but not the same). So there's no point in redefining them. As you have 4 models and 8 mappers+extractors I think that this is the case I'm talking about. They're probably doing the same "query result to model" mapping and you should omit one of them. But if you say that your XRowMapper and XResultSetExtractor don't do the same "query result to model mapping" then there's nothing to omit.

Rowmappers are higher level so if I could do the job with them I would choose them and omit each domain models' resultsetextractor.

Comment: all of them executes different queries to different tables, is this still reasonable?  is there any implementation?? or an example on what you are saying? since I am kinda lost

Comment: If you use an extractor and a mapper for the same table, it is redundant. Even the queries are different you can implement all of them by using just one of them. Take a look at [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) for rowmapper and [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?51731-JDBCTemplate-or-SimpleJDBCTemplate-example-using-ResultSetExtractor) for resultSetExtractor. You just create an object, fill it with your db values using the resultset and return the new object. There's no need for using both types of objects in your case.